# Crear archivo no legible, encriptado y verificar si fue manipulado. JAVA

Tags: java-8

Buen dia.
Quiero hacer un modulo que genere un archivo JSON o EXCEL pero que no pueda ser legible por el usuario y al momento de leerlo desde mi proyecto pueda extraer los datos

Tambien saber si ese archivo fue manipulado de alguna forma

¿Hay alguna libreria para hacer esto?

Comment: Así como los PDF, estos documentos ya tienen incluida esta funcionalidad para cifrar y descifrar